# Comparing 2 Same Decimal Numbers But Gives Wrong Result

Tags: php

I have this if condition :

```
if ($dc_real_vol != $dc_sum_vol) {
    echo '||+++ REAL VOL ' . $dc_real_vol . PHP_EOL;
    echo '||+++ SUM VOL ' . $dc_sum_vol . PHP_EOL;
    echo '||+++ THIS TRADE IS DAMAGE ' . PHP_EOL;
}
```

when I checked the output :

```
||+++ REAL VOL 0.60533000
||+++ SUM VOL 0.60533
||+++ THIS TRADE IS DAMAGE
```

why PHP consider `0.60533000` as different with `0.60533`? how to make this condition marked as true?

**update :**

I tried solution from Loek below, and I changed my code like this :

```
$dc_real_vol = (float) $dc_real_vol;
$dc_sum_vol = (float) $dc_sum_vol;

echo '||*** REAL VOL ' . $dc_real_vol . PHP_EOL;
echo '||*** SUM VOL ' . $dc_sum_vol . PHP_EOL;

if ($dc_real_vol !== $dc_sum_vol) {

    var_dump($dc_real_vol);
    var_dump($dc_sum_vol);

    echo '||+++ THIS TRADE IS DAMAGE ' . PHP_EOL;
}
```

and here's the result :

```
||*** REAL VOL 0.60533
||*** SUM VOL 0.60533
float(0.60533)
float(0.60533)
||+++ THIS TRADE IS DAMAGE
```

why same number, same type but PHP still recognised as different thing?

Comment: Relevant reading over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: Real numbers don’t have trailing zeros after the decimal point. So if outputting an unformatted “number” gives you `0.60533000`, then you did not have an actual numeric value to begin with, but a string.

Comment: *"why PHP consider 0.60533000 as different with 0.60533"* -- are they numbers or strings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't really explain why PHP thinks the numbers are different, I just know that they in fact **are** different at byte level.

The easiest way I can think of is to cast both numbers to a float and then just proceed as you normally would: https://3v4l.org/uQdAP

```
// Note we can even use !== instead of != now
if ((float) $dc_real_vol !== (float) $dc_sum_vol) {
    echo '||+++ REAL VOL ' . $dc_real_vol . PHP_EOL;
    echo '||+++ SUM VOL ' . $dc_sum_vol . PHP_EOL;
    echo '||+++ THIS TRADE IS DAMAGE ' . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Comment: I tried your solution, bro. but still gives me same result.

Comment: That's because this isn't a solution. You are attempting to compare small numbers (most likely in a cryptocoin trading app) so just use strings as `number_format`

Comment: @SaintRobson but it works based on the code and numbers you gave us? https://3v4l.org/LAZ0b

Comment: This is a bad solution because he's using this with crypto. Due to the limitations of float precision, it's best to just keep strings and avoid casting `(float)` to the variables.

Comment: Yeah sure, but I don't know anything about crypto and that isn't in the question. Upvoted your answer since it's clear and concise, but that doesn't make mine bad based on what the question provided me with.

Comment: @Loek fair enough.

Comment: @Loek please check my update above. I tried to `var_dump` also.

Comment: @Loek he's right. when I tried with `number_format`, PHP recognised as same thing. thank you for your answer and thanks to you, Mike.

Comment: Glad to help. Still wondering why your updated code doesn't work though. Probably floating point precision getting in the way.

Answer (score 1):

Format the numbers prior to comparison.

```
$dc_real_vol = number_format($dc_real_vol, 9);
$dc_sum_vol = number_format($dc_sum_vol, 9);
```

The actual reason your comparison isn't working is because you are most likely assigning these variables as `strings`. PHP is weak typing. You can verify this by checking your variables prior to comparison with `var_dump`. Most likely PHP will report it has typed your variables as strings. In which case, you should utilize `number_format` to properly compare them.

Comment: This seems to work, even for strings: https://3v4l.org/XPOHl . Like to point out that there is not such thing as 'loose' typing however. It's either static/dynamic or weak/strong.

Comment: @Loek fixed to "weak". I was mistakenly referring to the comparison.